# WPF centering a window wihout Window.Owner

Tags: wpf, window

I have a main window that has four private windows that are initialized in the constructor of the main window. One of the four windows is shown whenever the appropriate button is clicked and is hidden whenever the user presses the X of the appropriate window. If the user calls the window while it is still shown it simply goes into focus.

The idea is to sort of have a singleton pattern on the four windows, and to avoid making them modal dialogues.

What I want, however, is to have the four windows be displayed at the center of the main window, whenever one of them is "called".

I tried using the `Owner` property but the always-on-top behavior is quite annoying.

Is there a clean way to do this, or should I change the position of the called window through a formula that will take into account the size and position of the main and called window?